# Given the distances from incenter to vertices of a triangle, what are its sides' lengths?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given a triangle  $ABC$ with incenter $I$  and given the distances $AI$, $BI$ and $CI$.

What are the lengths $AB$, $AC$ and $BC$ of the sides?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is given?

Comment: @Lelouch What isn't clear ?

Comment: 'Given a triangle ABC'. What exactly is given? The points A,B,C or what?

Comment: If you want to have it that way only the location of the incenter is given and the distances to the vertexes

Answer (score 2):

They are given by the roots of a cubic. [By Stewart's theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Length_of_Angle_Bisector) the squared length of the $A$ angle bisector is given by $\frac{bc}{(b+c)^2}\left((b+c)^2-a^2\right)$, so by Van Obel's theorem $AI^2=\frac{bc}{a^2}\left((b+c)^2-
a^2\right)$.

To find $a,b,c$ from $AI^2,BI^2,CI^2$ is, in general, [impossible with straightedge and compass only](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/TriangleFromBisectors.shtml).

Comment: I think there is a typo, it should be $AI^2=\frac{bc}{(a+b+c)^2}((b+c)^2-a^2).$

Comment: Right. Using Barycentric coordinate distance formula can get this.